# Flutter throws "Unexpected null value" on autofill events (Web only)

Tags: flutter, web, browser, key, autofill

Whenever I try to fill out my form in web (Safari or Chrome) I get an `Unexpected null value` error. Upon inspection I noticed that the browser recognizes the autofill as a keyboard event. In `keyboard_binding.dart` on line 369 we can see that _handleEvent is expecting the event object to contain a keyboard key.

Flutter version: 3.7.5
OS: MacOS 13.2.1
Platform: Chrome 111.0.5563.64

[Error during app session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rQ2a.png)

Flutter doctor:

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.5, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64, locale en-BG)
• Flutter version 3.7.5 on channel stable at /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.0.5/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision c07f788888 (3 weeks ago), 2023-02-22 17:52:33 -0600
• Engine revision 0f359063c4
• Dart version 2.19.2
• DevTools version 2.20.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
• Android SDK at /Users/usr/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 14C18
• CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.76.1)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.61.20230301

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64
• Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 111.0.5563.64

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!

Minimal reproducible code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const CommonFieldsScreen());
}

class CommonFieldsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const CommonFieldsScreen({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    final firstNameController = TextEditingController();
    final lastNameController = TextEditingController();

    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                    width: 330,
                    child: Form(
                        key: formKey,
                        child: AutofillGroup(
                            child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            TextFormField(
                              controller: firstNameController,
                              decoration:
                                  const InputDecoration(hintText: 'First Name'),
                              autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.givenName],
                              validator: _requiredValidator,
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                                controller: lastNameController,
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: 'Last Name'),
                                autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.familyName],
                                validator: _requiredValidator),
                            Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  if (formKey.currentState?.validate() ??
                                      false) {
                                    firstNameController.clear();
                                    lastNameController.clear();
                                  }
                                },
                                child: const Text('Submit Form'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )))))));
  }

  String? _requiredValidator(String? value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) return 'Required';
    return null;
  }
}
```

Error log using `Flutter run --verbose`:

> [+141363 ms] Error: Unexpected null value.
> dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49      throw*
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 561:63  nullCheck
> lib/_engine/engine/keyboard_binding.dart 369:38                                   [_handleEvent]
> lib/_engine/engine/keyboard_binding.dart 582:7                                    handleEvent
> lib/_engine/engine/keyboard_binding.dart 97:25                                    
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 367:37  _checkAndCall
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 372:39  dcall
> lib/_engine/engine/keyboard_binding.dart 139:23                                   loggedHandler
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 367:37  _checkAndCall
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 372:39  dcall
> [  +21 ms] Error: Unexpected null value.
> dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49      throw*
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 561:63  nullCheck
> lib/_engine/engine/keyboard_binding.dart 369:38                                   [_handleEvent]
> lib/_engine/engine/keyboard_binding.dart 582:7                                    handleEvent
> lib/_engine/engine/keyboard_binding.dart 100:25                                   
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 367:37  _checkAndCall
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 372:39  dcall
> lib/_engine/engine/keyboard_binding.dart 139:23                                   loggedHandler
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 367:37  _checkAndCall
> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 372:39  dcall

I don't think there's much I can do on my side to fix this as it seems to be an internal Flutter bug. When I wrapped my widget inside of `KeyboardListener` I wasn't even able to detect the autofill event.

Answer (score 4):

I also have this problem. 2023.08.18
This is in an email field, and caused when I type 1 letter then select the email from the provided list.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.0, on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 6.2.0-26-generic, locale en_CA.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 3.13.0 on channel stable at /home/doug/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision efbf63d9c6 (3 days ago), 2023-08-15 21:05:06 -0500
    • Engine revision 1ac611c64e
    • Dart version 3.1.0
    • DevTools version 2.25.0


Error: Unexpected null value.
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:49      throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 855:63  nullCheck
lib/_engine/engine/keyboard_binding.dart 372:38                                   [_handleEvent]
lib/_engine/engine/keyboard_binding.dart 582:7                                    handleEvent
lib/_engine/engine/keyboard_binding.dart 98:18                                    <fn>
lib/_engine/engine/keyboard_binding.dart 140:16                                   loggedHandler
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 574:37  _checkAndCall
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 579:39  dcall
```

I tried editing the file in ./snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/keyboard_binding.dart
but it had no effect. I can not find anywhere else to edit it.

The only fix is unsatisfactory: I commented out the AutofillHints: part of the TextFormField.

Probably from code:
void _handleEvent(FlutterHtmlKeyboardEvent event) {
final Duration timeStamp = _eventTimeStampToDuration(event.timeStamp!);

```
final String eventKey = event.key!;
```

I suspect that event.key is null, if no key was pressed but the TextFormField was filled in by clicking on a menu choice.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be common issue  ->  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/114620

With P2 Priority.

> The P2 label indicates issues that we agree are important to work on,
> but are not at the top of the work list. This is the default level for
> new issues.
>
> **A bug at this priority level may not be fixed for a long
> time.**